# jump to the top of the page before transitioning to the route

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, ember.js

I have this website I am building with ember and liquid-fire. You can see it here.

https://portfolioilteris.herokuapp.com

The problem that I have is when I scroll to the middle of the page, and click on any logo on the left to go to the route, there's a quick jump to the top of the page and then transition happens.

Same thing happens on the reverse transition.

I am using the transition code from predefined beautiful liquid-fire library.

https://github.com/ef4/liquid-fire/tree/master/app/transitions

Is there a way to avoid this jump?

this is my css file

https://github.com/ilteris/portfolioSite/blob/master/app/styles/app.css#L101-L249

Best

Answer (score 0):

Implement a click handler on the component, pass in the event, and call preventDefault on it

Comment: thanks for the response @chris. Can you clarify when component are you referring to please?

Comment: You didn't post any code so I'm not sure. The point I'm making is this isn't an ember or a liquid fire issue. It's the default behaviour of a hyperlink, so you have to prevent the default behaviour. Are you using the link-to helper or just hard-coding the link in the template?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the response. I am using link-to helper. You can see it here: https://github.com/ilteris/portfolioSite/blob/master/app/templates/works.hbs#L10-L13